# EntityFramework Not Loading Related Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have these entities:

```
public class Company : PrimaryKey
{
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public virtual Account Account {get;set;}
}

public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company {get;set;}
}
```

I use these configurations:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasOptional(c => c.Account)
    .WithRequired(a => a.Company)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Now, I have two projects, one is a test bench project which is a `Console Application` with a `DbContext` and a `Repository`, the second is the full blown production project which is a `MVC 4` in which I use `Dependancy Injection` to create a Repository  `.InTransientScope()` which in turn loads a new context each time it is called.

Both have exactly the same contexts and repositories (the product obviously has Interfaces).

in the test bench when I call this:

```
_repository.GetById<Company>(id);
```

All of it properties are filled out, i.e. eager loading

in the production when I call the same line, nothing is loaded and its not loaded till I created another function which does this:

```
_dbContext.Companies.Include("Account").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
```

Of which, when executed does provide all the `Account` information, but funnily bar any other navigation properties that `Account` contains!!! Even though I have disable LazyLoading, it still doesn't work.

This is surprising because both projects are fundamentally the same, bar the use of the IoC DI in one of them....

Why is this happening? How can I specify in a predominantly generic Repository to eager load all this information at the `Controllers` preference....?

***Break Points***

I set break points in both projects too look at the ADO.NET call to the database and the sql statement that was executed, in the test bench it did go off and call the information, in the production it did not show any joins or anything of that nature what so ever.

***Other Things Tried***

I tried accessing the navigation property directly when loading it from the database:

```
var acc = _repository.GetById<Company>(id).Account;
```

It still says `null`. So my repository/context is not even loading any related data when asked for it.... what is going on?!

***Definitions***

```
_repository.GetById<Company>(id);
```

is:

```
public T GetById<T>(Guid id)
{
    return _dbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
}
```

Comment: Can you show how `_repository.GetById` is implemented? Is lazy loading disabled? (I'm confused by the sentence "*Even though I have disable LazyLoading, it still doesn't work*" - as if you would expect that disabling lazy loading could improve anything ...)

Comment: I assume that by disabling lazy loading would infer that it would use eager loading.... @Slauma

Comment: Disabling lazy loading just means that no navigation property will be loaded at all. Eager loading is really applying `Include(...)` explicitly. It never happens automatically.

Comment: Ahh I see... I will keep it enabled then!

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, I have no idea why.. I haven't tampered with anything. The only thing that I have, was to put `.InTransientScope()` onto `IDbContextFactory<MyContext>`

I actually enabled all Lazy Loading everywhere I could, and it now works.... but it's strange that when I started on the Production project I never even tampered with Lazy Loading at all, but since I extented the `Model` and added `modelBuilder` stuff I have had to specifically tell it to Lazy Load.